# cache response in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a scenario where I want to cache a JSON response and use it further.
I have total two requests out of which one I want to cache and use the response in another request, however the other request should not be cached. As of now what I have tried cache's all the requests.
Here is what I have tried :

```
import requests
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache('test_cache', expire_after=120)
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/')
print(r.content)
r1 = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/nocach')
print(r1.content)
```

Here I want only the requests should be cached for `r` and not for `r1` .

Is there any other way that supports my scenario as of now I am using `requests-cache` which caches all requests , however my desired scenario woudl be not to cache all request but the ones that I want to be cached for specific time.

How can I achieve this any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a feature in `requests_cache` to temporarily disable the cache feature. This is the method `.disabled()`. In the following snippet I use the `with` keyword to create the temporary scope in which the requests are not cached.

```
import requests
import requests_cache
requests_cache.install_cache('test_cache', expire_after=120)
r = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/')
print(r.content)
with requests_cache.disabled():
    r1 = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/nocach')
    print(r1.content)
```

Additionally, you can add a check if it was fetched from cache with the attribute `from_cache`

```
r1 = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/nocach')
print( hasattr(r1, 'from_cache') )
```

wich should return `False` if it was placed in the `disabled` cache code context

Comment: Worked as a charm thanks !! but would using `wit` statements lead to slower code execution in python ?

Comment: Great! No, `with` is just a control-flow mechanism and can be likened to a `if-else` block.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how can i access the cached data.

Comment: @NeedToCodeAgain sure, try
    print(requests_cache.get_cache())
    print('Cached URLS:')
    print('\n'.join(requests_cache.get_cache().urls))

Comment: Thank you @pastaleg for the prompt response, actualy i want to save "r.text" which is in json to cache and in the second api request i want to access the cache. I tried but not able to figure out how i can do this.

Comment: @NeedToCodeAgain if you're using the code above that should happen in the background. No need to specifically access cache. If you're having trouble make a new Stackoverflow question with your code so I can see it. Feel free to link it as a comment reply here :)

Comment: Hi @pastaleg, can you please have a look at the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74793739/cache-api-response-and-access-it-in-the-upcoming-api-request

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1: CachedSession

Alternatively, you can use [requests_cache.CachedSession](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html) to cache requests instead of `install_cache()`, and a regular [requests.Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) (or just `requests.get()`) for non-cached requests:

```py
import requests
from requests_cache import CachedSession

session = CachedSession('test_cache', expire_after=120)

# Cached request
r = session.get('http://localhost:5000/')
print(r)

# Non-cached request
r1 = requests.get('http://localhost:5000/nocache')
print(r1)
```

## Option 2: URL patterns

Another option, as of **requests-cache 0.7+**, is to use [URL glob patterns](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/expiration.html#expiration-with-url-patterns) to define which requests to cache. This works with both `CachedSession` and `install_cache()`, and is especially useful if you want to set a different expiration for different hosts.

```py
from requests_cache import CachedSession

urls_expire_after = {
    'https://httpbin.org/get': 120,   # Cache for 2 minutes
    'https://httpbin.org/delay': -1,  # Cache indefinitely
    'https://httpbin.org/ip': 0,      # Don't cache
}
session = CachedSession('test_cache', urls_expire_after=urls_expire_after)

# Cached request with expiration
r = session.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
print(r)

# Cached request with no expiration
r1 = session.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/1')
print(r1)

# Non-cached request
r2 = session.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
print(r2)
```